# How to add paired values in sub-lists separately?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of lists:

```
a = [[2,3,4,5],[1,3,2,7]]
```

and I want to sum consecutive paired values in each sub-list separately to output:

```
[[5,9],[4,9]]
```

and using following but not getting as needed:

```
b = [sum(a[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(0,len(a),2)]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension.

```
>>> a = [[2,3,4,5],[1,3,2,7]]
>>> [[sum(sublist[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(0,len(sublist),2)] for sublist in a]
[[5, 9], [4, 9]]
```

Equivalent, easier to read version using a function:

```
>>> def paired_sum(a):
...     return [sum(a[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(0,len(a),2)]
... 
>>> [paired_sum(sublist) for sublist in a]
[[5, 9], [4, 9]]
>>> map(paired_sum, a)
[[5, 9], [4, 9]]
```